# How to render StructBlock which is inside StreamBlock to template?

Tags: django, wagtail

How can I render heading, text, image in my carousel_block.html template. I can't access these. Here is my code.

My custom block

```
class CarouselBlock(blocks.StreamBlock):
    carousel_items = blocks.StructBlock([
        ('heading', blocks.CharBlock(label='Nadpis', max_length=128)),
        ('text', blocks.CharBlock(label='Text')),
        ('image', ImageChooserBlock(label='Obrázek')),
    ])

    class Meta:
        template = 'cms/blocks/carousel_block.html'
```

This is my html template, where I want to render heading, text and image

```
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
    {% for carousel_items in self.carousel_items %}
        {% image carousel_items.value.image max-1920x1080 as image_1920 %}
        <div class="carousel-item {% if forloop.first %}active{% endif %} ">
            <section class="banner-area" id="home" style="background-image: url({{ image_1920.url }})">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-start align-items-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 banner-left">
                            <h1 class="text-white">
                                {{ carousel_items.value.heading }}
                            </h1>
                            <p class="mx-auto text-white  mt-20 mb-40">
                                {{ carousel_items.value.text }}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </section>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}

        <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
            <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
        </a>
        <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
            <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
            <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
{% for carousel_items in self.carousel_items %}
```

should be:

```
{% for carousel_items in self %}
```

(although I'd suggest calling the variable `carousel_item` instead of `carousel_items`, since it refers to a single item in the stream.)

Within the `cms/blocks/carousel_block.html` template, `self` refers to the StreamBlock value - this is a list-like object, not a dictionary, so it doesn't have a `carousel_items` property. When you loop over it, you'll get a sequence of block objects which have a `block_type` (which will always be `'carousel_items'` in your case, as there's only one available block type here) and a `value`.

Comment: Thank you very much. It was so easy to solve, but I wasnt able to do it. I am feeling a bit stupid 